iPad bluetooth keyboard - fn / "globe" key not recognised
iPad Mini 5th gen running iOS 17.6.1
Omoton KB066 wireless keyboard (European/ISO key layout)

Holding cmd on the keyboard brings up the shortcuts.
None of the ones using the function/globe key work.
Has anyone else had a problem like this with a bluetooth keyboard?
I used the Monkeytype key tester - the Fn key is sending ctrl+space, is this correct? (Same result when pairing both with an iPad and the Mac Mini I am typing this on now.)
Is anyone aware of another key combination that'll emulate the Fn key?

The keyboard is sending F1-F12 correctly when Fn is held down.
The iPad had been setup with English/French keyboards, but I removed French to rule that out.
Multiple power cycles and pairings in attempt to reset.
Shouldn't be relevant, but the "Full keyboard access" setting is turned off.
By way of comparison, pressing Fn on my Keychron mechanical keyboard doesn't appear to send a code at all

(On a related note, as well as the Fn button not working, holding cmd on my iPhone (SE 3rd gen, iOS 17) when the keyboard is paired with that doesn't do anything at all, though you can type and use basic shortcuts like formatting text, handling tabs in Safari, returning to the home screen etc.)

Ask Omoton support as well, there might be some setting on the hardware that affects this.

@TomGewecke thanks. I have and have swapped it to one they suggested. Identical model number, very different layout (look for the square "home" button top left, and no globe key). Hasn't really solved the problem - I can map the Ctrl key to Globe, can't map the Fn key to anything, and (and this feels like it's Apple's fault) the button you're supposed to be able to use to show available shortcuts (sometimes Globe, sometimes Command, because shrugs) works in some apps, not in others, and starts/stops working at random. Think board itself is ok.  Maybe things will be better in iPadOS 18…
